# Are the deduction rules for NTTPs the same as variables?

Tags: c++, c++20

I would expect the deduction rules for variables and NTTPs to work the same. However, GCC—opposed to Clang and MSVC—seems to preserve the const-ness when deducing the type of NTTP `A`. What is the verdict of the C++20 standard when it comes to the deduction rules of NTTPs opposed to variables?

```cpp
#include <concepts>

template<auto A>
using a = decltype(A);

struct s {};
struct t { static constexpr auto n = s{}; };

static_assert(std::same_as<a<t::n>, s>); // fails on GCC 13.2
static_assert([]<typename T = t>{
    return std::same_as<a<T::n>, s>; // fails on GCC 13.2 and trunk
}());
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/1Gof9oc75)

---

GCC's error message:

```cpp
<source>:9:20: error: static assertion failed
    9 | static_assert(std::same_as<a<t::n>, s>);
      |               ~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:9:20: note: constraints not satisfied
In file included from <source>:1:
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-13.2.0/include/c++/13.2.0/concepts:57:15:
required for the satisfaction of '__same_as<_Tp, _Up>' [with _Tp = const s; _Up = s]
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-13.2.0/include/c++/13.2.0/concepts:57:32:
note: the expression 'is_same_v<_Tp, _Up> [with _Tp = const s; _Up = s]'
evaluated to 'false'
   57 |       concept __same_as = std::is_same_v<_Tp, _Up>;
      |                           ~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: For those who come in the future: NTTP -> **N**on-**T**ype **T**emplate **P**arameter.

Answer (score 4):

This is [CWG Issue 2777](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#2777). It mentions two pieces of verbiage that seem to affect implementation divergence:

> [temp.param]/8 An id-expression naming a non-type template-parameter of class type `T` denotes a static storage duration object of type `const T`, known as a template parameter object, whose value is that of the corresponding template argument after it has been converted to the type of the template-parameter. ...

And

> [dcl.type.decltype]/1 For an expression `E`, the type denoted by `decltype(E)` is defined as follows:
>
> - otherwise, if E is an unparenthesized id-expression naming a non-type template-parameter (13.2 [temp.param]), `decltype(E)` is the type of the template-parameter after performing any necessary type deduction (9.2.9.7 [dcl.spec.auto], 9.2.9.8 [dcl.type.class.deduct]);

It's currently unresolved, though the resolution it proposes would make GCC's behavior<sup>1</sup> correct (by virtue of a currently non-normative note the issue proposes to turn into normative text).

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> - Note that GCC 13.2 doesn't "preserve const-ness", but considers the type of A implicitly const (as the issue discusses).</sub>

Comment: While the resolution might make GCC's behavior correct, it doesn't seem to be the direction where GCC is heading. As the first assertion fails on GCC 13.2 but compiles fine on GCC trunk. The 2nd assertion failing on GCC trunk (where `n` now becomes dependent on `T`) is probably an oversight on their end. This leaves the impression to *not* expect the type of `A` to be implicitly `const` until the resolution is accepted.

Comment: Also, the description of `decltype` on [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype) actually seems to indicate that the yielded type should be non-const: *"If the argument is an unparenthesized id-expression naming a non-type template parameter, then decltype yields the type of the template parameter (after performing any necessary type deduction if the template parameter is declared with a placeholder type). **The type is non-const even if the entity is a template parameter object (which is a const object)**."*